# What is the purpose of a Stream.Builder in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

To put it differently, what do I gain by using `Stream.Builder.add()` to add items to the builder and then using `Stream.Builder.build()`, versus adding the items in a collection or array and creating a Stream from that?

I assume there is a benefit somewhere in some circumstances but it's not obvious to me...

Comment: The Javadoc says it is used [_without the copying overhead that comes from using an ArrayList as a temporary buffer_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the machine has enough memory, using `Stream.Builder` allows to add more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements to it.

Internally, `Stream.Builder` uses a `SpinedBuffer`, which is a non public class.

From `SpinedBuffer` docs:

> An ordered collection of elements.  Elements can be added, but not removed.
> Goes through a building phase, during which elements can be added, and a
> traversal phase, during which elements can be traversed in order but no
> further modifications are possible.
>
> One or more arrays are used to store elements. The use of a multiple
> arrays has better performance characteristics than a single array used by
> `ArrayList`, as when the capacity of the list needs to be increased
> no copying of elements is required.  This is usually beneficial in the case
> where the results will be traversed a small number of times.

So, it also avoids `ArrayList` resizing.

Answer (score 4):

It has a very interesting internal data structure that is highly optimized for insertions, without the possibility of removal or random access.

Your `array` and/or `Collection` pay an additional price for all *other* functionality that they support.

Comment: ...and most importantly, you pay a cost in how the the common behavior of adding items behaves when the internal buffer(s) need to be enlarged/added.

Comment: @Steve it is not _that_ expensive to resize the inner array. Ever wondered why `List::toArray` does `return toArray(generator.apply(0))` internally?

Comment: Did I comment on the severity of the cost?  I assume you're saying that the difference in the cost of insertion isn't so different than the cost assumed by the functions that aren't even available on the internal data structure.  If that is what you're saying, I ask you, how many times do you need to use those functions to equal the overhead of copying a large ArrayList buffer the third or fourth time it needs to be resized?

Comment: @Steve nvm, I miss-read what you have said. and yes - you do pay a cost for the copying and creation of the new array, that is why this `Builder` exists. My point was that _in general_ the copying cost is rather small. As an example I brought that function that instead of doing `toArray(generator.apply(x)` where `x` would be the known current size of the `List`, sets it to `0`.

Comment: @fps ...Shipilev... arrays wisdom of the ancient?

Comment: @Steve This article explains Eugene's point [https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/)